# Как сделать "выпуклые" границы у блока?

Tags: html, css, css3, html5

Мне нужно сделать логотип YouTube`a.Так вот, как сделать так, чтобы границы логотипа были "выпуклыми". Пробовал при помощи border-radius, но у меня особо не получилось.

Пример: https://jsfiddle.net/deloop_/z308ryja/4/

```css
#logo_tube {
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: #FF0000;
  width: 80px;
  height: 45px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  position: absolute;
  top: calc(50% - 22.5px);
  left: calc(50% - 40px);
}

#logo_triangle {
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: transparent;
  position: relative;
  top: 12px;
  left: calc(50% - 5px);
  border: 10px solid transparent;
  border-left: 10px solid white;
  z-index: 1;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div id="logo_tube" class="stop">
    <div id="logo_triangle" class="stop"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Скорее всего ты не на тот селектор применяешь правила, скинь больше кода

Comment: @ВладимирВладимирович , 
https://jsfiddle.net/deloop_/z308ryja/4/

Comment: Не делайте так, скачайте картинку логотипа и используйте её. В настоящем логотипе YouTube нет никакой выпуклости (и вообще форма не та)

Comment: @andreymal , да нет, есть там выпуклости. Юрий понял меня и ответил мне на вопрос. А картинку не мог использовать, ибо мне нужно сделать анимацию некоторых частей самого логотипа.

Comment: Если имеются в виду выпуклости как в ответе Юрия, тогда окей. В любом случае YouTube вам [**запрещает**](https://www.youtube.com/intl/ru/yt/about/brand-resources/) искажать логотип (в том числе, очевидно, делать анимацию), поэтому откажитесь от анимации и просто скачайте картинку

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как-то так... в качестве варианта.

```css
#logo_tube_h {
      display: inline-block;
      background-color: #FF0000;
      width: 90px;
      height: 40px;
      border-radius: 10px/30px;
      position: absolute;
      top: calc(50% - 20px);
      left: calc(50% - 45px);
        z-index: 1;

}
#logo_tube_v {
   display: inline-block;
  background-color: #FF0000;
  width: 80px;
  height: 48px;
  border-radius: 30px/5px;
  position: absolute;
  top: calc(50% - 24px);
  left: calc(50% - 40px);
    z-index: -1;

}        

#logo_triangle {
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: transparent;
  position: relative;
  top: 12px;
  left: calc(50% - 5px);
  border: 10px solid transparent;
  border-left: 10px solid white;
  z-index: 1;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div id="logo_tube_v" class="stop">
  </div>
  <div id="logo_tube_h" class="stop">
    <div id="logo_triangle" class="stop"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Допустим так, с параметрами "выпуклости" поиграйся

```html
<style>
#logo_tube {
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: #FF0000;
  width: 80px;
  height: 45px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  position: absolute;
  top: calc(50% - 22.5px);
  left: calc(50% - 40px);
  box-shadow:inset -5px -5px 5px 0 rgba(0,0,0,.5), 
             inset 5px 5px 5px 0 rgba(255,255,255,0.5);
}


#logo_triangle {
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: transparent;
  position: relative;
  top: 12px;
  left: calc(50% - 5px);
  border: 10px solid transparent;
  border-left: 10px solid white;
  z-index: 1;  
}
</style>

<div id = "container">
  <div id = "logo_tube" class = "stop">
    <div id = "logo_triangle" class = "stop"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: рекомендуется к прочтению перед ответом - https://www.youtube.com/intl/ru/yt/about/brand-resources/#logos-icons-colors

Comment: @UModeL, а мне то зачем перед ответом это читать? Пусть вопрошающий читает перед использованием

Comment: Вы провоцируете вопрошающего на использование некорректного значка))

Comment: @UModeL, вот я щас к тебе с товарищем майором приду и лицензию на windows и на остальной софт до кучи проверю! ;)

Comment: так Linux же...

Comment: Спасибо, но не совсем так. Юрий понял меня и помог мне с проблемой, но вам тоже спасибо :)

Простите меня, что не так объяснил. Уверен, что если бы я нормально объяснил сам вопрос, то вы бы мне тоже помогли :)

Answer (score 0):

```css
#logo_tube {
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: #FF0000;
  width: 70px;
  height: 50px;
  border-radius: 50%/20%;
  position: absolute;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  top: calc(50% - 22.5px);
  left: calc(50% - 40px);
}

#logo_triangle {
  font-size: 20px;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div id="logo_tube" class="stop">
    <div id="logo_triangle" class="stop">►</div>
  </div>
</div>
```